# Ignore FATAL Error in PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a PHP script which loops over a set of database records and tests these records against a web services.

The problem is that occasionally the Web Service will fail to load, yielding "Fatal Error Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '...' : failed to load external entity "..."

I really need to ignore this and move on processing...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I browsed at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584 and it seems this would be a "catchable fatal" (if such concept exists...), but this doesn't seem to be working... :(

Comment: Perhaps using ```use_soap_error_handler(true);``` could make your SOAP not to relay its errors to the default PHP handler.

Comment: `use_soap_error_handler` is only applicable to SoapServer, isn't it?

Comment: Does the WSDL really change with every request?  I would imagine that for a production type script you should allow the WSDL to be cached and not download and parse it with each request.

Comment: Excellent point @MikeBrant.  I could cache it to minimize impact.  One stupid question, though... What are the caching policies?  PHP docs are somewhat terse...  How can I ensure my PHP will pick up eventual changes (which are predictable and negotiable)?

Comment: @Pbal Check out this link for ini settings that determine cache behavior - http://php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php  You are probably most concerned with soap.wsdl_cache_ttl  When I used to work with SOAP API's I would typically turn on cache in testing environments and have the cache on in production environments.

Comment: Are you using xdebug? What are your versions?

Comment: Hello @Marek; I am not using Xdebug; PHP5.5.9, Zend Engine 2.5.0

Comment: @Pbal Try to add `array('exceptions' => true)` as second argument to `SoapClient` constructor.

Comment: Ok... Seems to be solved...  `exceptions` was missing and I was not placing the `SoapClient` constructor inside the `try`(duh...).  Now testing to check whether it's 100% stable.